# C# Key wrap/unwrap PBEWITHSHA256AND256BITAES CBC

Tags: c#, java, cryptography, aes, bouncycastle

I have the following code in Java doing key unwrap using **bouncy castle** provider:

```
private static byte[] unwrapKey(byte[] toUnwrap, String key) throws Exception {
    byte[] decoded = Base64.decode(toUnwrap);
    if (decoded == null || decoded.length <= 16) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Bad input data.");
    }
    byte[] salt = new byte[16];
    byte[] wrappedKey = new byte[decoded.length - 16];
    System.arraycopy(decoded, 0, salt, 0, 16);
    System.arraycopy(decoded, 16, wrappedKey, 0, decoded.length - 16);
    PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(key.toCharArray());
    SecretKey wrapperKey = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWITHSHA256AND256BITAES-CBC-BC").generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);
    PBEParameterSpec parameterSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, 10);
    Cipher decCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding", bcProvider);
    decCipher.init(Cipher.UNWRAP_MODE, wrapperKey, parameterSpec);
    return decCipher.unwrap(wrappedKey, "AES", Cipher.SECRET_KEY).getEncoded();
}
```

Now, I need to do the same in `C#`. The problem is that even though there's a port of BC to C#, I still can not get it working. Tried different things, and always get some exceptions.

For example, this code throws "pad block corrupted" exception at the second last line:

```
byte[] decoded = Convert.FromBase64String(toUnwrap);
if (decoded == null || decoded.Length <= 16) {
    throw new System.ArgumentException("Bad input data", "toUnwrap");
}
byte[] salt = new byte[16];
byte[] wrappedKey = new byte[decoded.Length - 16];
Array.Copy(decoded, 0, salt, 0, 16);
Array.Copy(decoded, 16, wrappedKey, 0, decoded.Length - 16);
int iterationCount = 10;
String alg = "PBEWithSHA256And256BitAES-CBC-BC";
Asn1Encodable defParams = PbeUtilities.GenerateAlgorithmParameters(alg, salt, iterationCount);
char[] password = key.ToCharArray();
IWrapper wrapper = WrapperUtilities.GetWrapper(alg);
ICipherParameters parameters = PbeUtilities.GenerateCipherParameters(alg, password, defParams);
wrapper.Init(false, parameters);
byte[] pText = wrapper.Unwrap(wrappedKey, 0, wrappedKey.Length);
return pText.ToString();
```

I suspect that C# uses different type of padding by default, but no idea how to force "NoPadding" as in Java code.

I'm not sure, if JAVA code use rfc3994 is this case or not, because in RFC you need to provide IV, while here there's a salt, but no IV.

I wonder if anyone did it before and if so, what would be c# analogy.

Comment: What are the exceptions that you get?

Comment: added code to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured that out:

```
public static String unwrapKey(String toUnwrap, String key)
{
    byte[] decoded = Convert.FromBase64String(toUnwrap);
    if (decoded == null || decoded.Length <= 16)
    {
        throw new System.ArgumentException("Bad input data", "toUnwrap");
    }
    byte[] salt = new byte[16];
    byte[] wrappedKey = new byte[decoded.Length - 16];
    Array.Copy(decoded, 0, salt, 0, 16);
    Array.Copy(decoded, 16, wrappedKey, 0, decoded.Length - 16);
    int iterationCount = 10;
    String algSpec = "AES/GCM/NoPadding";
    String algName = "PBEWithSHA256And256BitAES-CBC-BC";

    Asn1Encodable defParams = PbeUtilities.GenerateAlgorithmParameters(algName, salt, iterationCount);
    char[] password = key.ToCharArray();
    IWrapper wrapper = WrapperUtilities.GetWrapper(algSpec);
    ICipherParameters parameters = PbeUtilities.GenerateCipherParameters(algName, password, defParams);
    wrapper.Init(false, parameters);
    byte[] keyText = wrapper.Unwrap(wrappedKey, 0, wrappedKey.Length);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(keyText);
}
```

This will do exactly the same as the JAVA code above.